# Getting error 'Function host is not running' when trying to access my Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

This happened all of a sudden to one azure functions service I have running, I tried rebuilding the functions locally and deploying them and restarting/stopping starting the service but it didn't work, creating a new azure functions app and deploying to it works though so I don't think it has to do with the functions themselves.

Looking at the functions not working I see the following error:

```
Error:

The function runtime is unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tokens: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.FluentBindingRule`1.BindToInput(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IAsyncConverter`2<!0,!!0>)'.
Session Id: 34919f56bb1241f5a05eb7a0918fe52f

Timestamp: 2018-03-31T09:15:44.338Z
```

Is there a way to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Looks like a support ticket to me. Not much you can troubleshoot there.

Comment: See https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your extensions to the latest version. There are now instructions of how to do this manually in the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension).

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94)https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94

also check your key in the configuration section of function app
all the configuration key should be properly mapped with your function app locally and remote both end.

after mapping kindly published the code and check it up and running